# Can I choose Needs Community Edit in Triage and then edit the post?

Tags: support, triage, review-suspension

I have been suspended from review because of my action on [this triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27620383).

The suspension message says:

> You’ve been suspended from reviewing. You will be able to review again in 6 days.
> The following tasks were handled incorrectly:
>
> /review/triage/27620383
>
> You chose the Flag action for questions that should be closed or can only be improved or clarified by the question-asker. The Needs community edit action should only be used when other community users (like yourself) are able to improve an answerable question with editing or formatting. When in doubt, use the Skip action.
>
> We understand this can be confusing, so thanks for doing what you can to help.
>
> In the meantime, you can refer to the help center article for more information and revisit your recent reviews.

At first, the jsfiddle link was not formated correctly so I choose *Needs Community Edit*.

After that I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64838047/timeline) the post and thought the post looked okay. Later, the question was closed and I got suspended.

So the question is: Can I choose *Needs Community Edit* and then edit the post? Or do I have to do the edit first then select *Looks OK*?

Comment: If a question can be closed for any reason, it must be closed (Flag/Needs author edit). Just keep this simple rule in mind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your specific example, code must be *in the question itself*. It is not acceptable for it to be hosted off-site like on jsfiddle. Because of this you should have chosen for the question to be closed for missing debugging details (Flag -> Needs Improvement -> A community-specific reason -> Needs debugging details), which is used for cases where:

> The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.**

You should only choose to edit posts where you can make a *meaningful* improvement to the post. If a question should be closed then it's generally better to leave any improvements to the post author.

I would suggest reading the [triage review queue "guide"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/). While a long read it contains a substantial amount of useful information and makes it clearer how you should act in different situations.

In short:

- Only use Looks OK when there is nothing at all wrong with the post (note that this is very rarely the case, most posts can do with a bit of tidying up)
- Only use Needs Community Edit when a community member (such as yourself) can edit the question to resolve *all* issues present.

  - Some issues should be resolved by the author, including editing code from off-site resources into the post, transcribing error messages/code from images into text, and translating their question into English.
  - It is *okay* to choose this option and then go and edit the post yourself (again, only edit the post if you're going to fix as many issues in the post as you're able, and if the post would be stay-open-worthy afterwards).
- Use Needs Author Edit or Flag for cases where the question should be closed.
- Use Skip whenever and however you like, this button should be your friend.